# Does this tetrahedron have a name?

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry, symmetry, polyhedra

Consider the tetrahedron with vertices at:

$$(0,0,0)$$
$$(2,-\sqrt2,0)$$
$$(2,\sqrt2,0)$$
$$(2,0,2)$$

This tetrahedron is not regular but does it have any notable properties? It appears to have some symmetries. For example, its faces are congruent. Its two long edges appear somehow symmetrical with respect to each other (and separate mutually perpendicular faces). Does the tetrahedron have a name?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Other_special_cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's called a tetragonal disphenoid,
sometimes a digonal antiprism.
However it is only an isogonal polyhedron.

--- rk

Comment: Other variations include the disphenoid tetrahedron. It is also isohedral. A polyhedron which is both isohedral and isogonal is known as a noble polyhedron.